# Referencing Text file in folder in ASP.NET Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I have a text file called name.txt in a folder called data. I would like to write to it but I'm having a difficult time trying to reference it. My attempt:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"data/", name + ".txt");
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);
file.WriteLine("Write something in file");
file.Close();
```

Unfortunately, the error I receive is the path does not exist. Is there a simple and easy way to get the file path of the folders in an ASP.NET project?

Thanks

Comment: Request for clarification: one of the tags is asp.net-core, is this an ASP.NET MVC project (.NET Framework) or an ASP.NET Core MVC project (.NET Core)?

Comment: Hi, Adam! It's an ASP.NET Core MVC project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things.

In ASP.NET Core, you'll want to retrieve the path that the app is running on from the `IWebHostEnvironment` interface. In the code below, you'll see in the constructor it's using Dependency Injection to get access to that.

It has two properties,

- `ContentRootPath` is the root of the application
- `WebRootPath` is the wwwroot folder

Also to simplify things I've refactored writing to the file with `File.WriteAllText()` which is a newer convenience wrapper around StreamWriter and does exactly what is shown in the answer.

Last thing that is personal preference I've opted for string interpolation `$""` instead of concatenating with the `+`.

```cs
    public class FileSystemFileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;

        public FileSystemFileController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(string name)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, $"data/{name}.txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "Write something on file");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this,

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"data/", name + ".txt");
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    file.Write("Write something on file");
}
file.Close();
```

Take note, `using` will fail on your second attempt, so you might want to look at the solution provided by @Danny Tuppeny on this question [how to create .txt file and write it c# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190689/how-to-create-txt-file-and-write-it-c-sharp-asp-net)

Regards,

Joey